# How to get visualization from module that executed in cycle or function?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have Python code in line of cells in Google.colab. Two cells of code implies manual input over images (BBoxWidget). Code  works good in cells. I hope to speed up and automate it but can not find the way. Is it possible to automate code with manual input?

One of widgets for manual input

```
IS_COLAB = True

if IS_COLAB:
    from google.colab import output
    output.enable_custom_widget_manager()

from jupyter_bbox_widget import BBoxWidget

widget = BBoxWidget()
widget.image = encode_image(IMAGE_PATH)
widget
```

This code uses GPU and Segment Anything Model so I suppose it is too heavy for a PC (and I could not run it in a Jupiter). But all my images less than 10MB

The only way I know is to merge cells in a cycle(s) or combine it in some functions and activate these functions. However code with functions/cycles executes without pauses for manual input.